# Display filename in next View too

Tags: swiftui

I have a code that makes a http Request, gets an array with filenames from that, displays them each with an image and the filename below. Everything works fine.
Now I made each image a button that opens a detail page.
That works but at the top it should say the matching filename from the page before.
But I am not able to hand over the filename (name) from ContentView4 to the next page (ts).

The language is SwiftUi

Could you please help me?

Thanks

Nikias

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView4: View {
    
    @State var showingDetail = false
    
    @State var username: String = "."
    @State var password: String = "."
    
    @State private var name = String("Nikias2")
    
    @State private var t = String()
    @State private var x = -1


    @State var dateien = ["word.png"]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {

        ZStack{
            VStack {
                ForEach(0 ..< dateien.count, id: \.self) {
                    Button(action: {
                        print("button pressed")
                        x = x + 1
                        t = dateien[x]
                        self.showingDetail.toggle()
                    }) {
                    Image("datei")
                    }
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .padding(0)
                    Text(self.dateien[$0])
                    Text(t)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented:
                $showingDetail) {
            ts(name: t)
                }
        .onAppear { //# This `onAppear` is added to `ZStack{...}`
            doHttpRequest()
        }

    }
    }
    
 func doHttpRequest() {
            let myUrl = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.180/int.php")! //# Trailing semicolon is not needed
            var request = URLRequest(url: myUrl)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string
            let postString = "Name=\($username)&Passwort=\($password)"
            
            request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
            
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
                (data, response, error) in
                
                //# Use if-let when you want to use the unwrapped value
                if let error = error {
                    print("error=\(error)")
                    return
                }
                
                //# Use guard-let when nil has no meaning and want to exit on nil
                guard let response = response else {
                    print("Unexpected nil response")
                    return
                }
                // You can print out response object
                print("response = \(response)")
                
                //Let's convert response sent from a server side script to a NSDictionary object:
                do {
                    //# Use guard-let when nil has no meaning and want to exit on nil
                    guard let data = data else {
                        print("Unexpected nil data")
                        return
                    }
                    //#1 `mutableContainer` has no meaning in Swift
                    //#2 Use Swift Dictionary type instead of `NSDictionary`
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any]
                    
                    if let parseJSON = json {
                        // Now we can access value of First Name by its key
                        //# Use if-let when you want to use the unwrapped value
                        if let firstNameValue = parseJSON["Name"] as? String {
                            print("firstNameValue: \(firstNameValue)")
                            let dateien =  firstNameValue.components(separatedBy: ",")
                            print(dateien)
                            
                            self.dateien = dateien
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView4()
    }
}


struct ts: View {
    @State var hin = false
    @State var um = false
    @State var datname: String = ""
    var name: String
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
        VStack {
            Text(name)
                .font(.system(size: 60))
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .padding(50)
            Button(action: {
                self.hin.toggle()
            }) {
            Text("+")
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding()
                .frame(width: 220, height: 60)
                .background(Color.yellow)
                .cornerRadius(35.0)
            }
            .padding()
            if hin {
                HStack {
                Text("Datei auswählen")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 70)
                    .background(Color.yellow)
                    .cornerRadius(20.0)
                    .animation(Animation.default)
                Text("Datei hochladen")
                    .font(.headline)
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 70)
                    .background(Color.yellow)
                    .cornerRadius(20.0)
                    .animation(Animation.default)
            }
            }
            Text("Datei herunterladen")
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding()
                .frame(width: 220, height: 60)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .cornerRadius(35.0)
        Button(action: {
                self.um.toggle()
            }) {
            Text("Datei umbenennen")
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding()
                .frame(width: 220, height: 60)
                .background(Color.green)
                .cornerRadius(35.0)
        }
                .padding()
                if um {
                    HStack {
                        TextField(name, text: $datname)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 70)
                        .cornerRadius(20.0)
                        .animation(Animation.default)
                    Text("Datei umbenennen")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .frame(width: 150, height: 70)
                        .background(Color.green)
                        .cornerRadius(20.0)
                        .animation(Animation.default)
                }
                }
            Text("Datei löschen")
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding()
                .frame(width: 220, height: 60)
                .background(Color.red)
                .cornerRadius(35.0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is a result of using `@State` variables to store all of the attributes.  `@State` variables are not consistent and get refreshed in the background by SwiftUI depending on your views visibility.
The piece that you are missing is a `view controller class` stored in an `@EnviornmentObject variable`. This class gets Initiated in your main contentView and is used to keep track and alter of all your attributes.
Each ContentView should reference the single @EnviornmentObject and pull data from that class.

Another solution which may work would be to replace all your @State variables with `@StateObject` vars.  `@StateObject` vars are basically `@State` vars but get initiated before the struct get loaded and the value is kept consistent regardless of the view state of the parent struct.

Here is a rough implementation of @EnvironmentObject within your project.
Basically use the @EnvironmentObject to pass values to child views

ContentView4.swift

```
struct ContentView4: View {
    
@EnvironmentObject cv4Controller: ContentView4Controller

     var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {

        ZStack{
            VStack {
                ForEach(0 ..< cv4Controller.dateien.count, id: \.self) {
                    Button(action: {
                        print("button pressed")
                        x = x + 1
                        t = cv4Controller.dateien[x]
                        self.showingDetail.toggle()
                    }) {
                    Image("datei")
                    }
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .padding(0)
                    Text(self.dateien[$0])
                    Text(cv4Controller.t)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented:
                cv4Controller.$showingDetail) {
            ts(name: cv4Controller.t)
                }
        .onAppear { //# This `onAppear` is added to `ZStack{...}`
            cv4Controller.doHttpRequest()
        }

    }
}
```

ContentView4Controller.swift

```
class ContentView4Controller: ObservableObject {

        @Published var showingDetail = false
        
        @Published var username: String = "."
        @Published var password: String = "."
        
        @Published private var name = String("Nikias2")
        
        @Published private var t = String()
        @Published private var x = -1

    
        @Published private var t = String()
        @Published private var x = -1


        @Published var dateien = ["word.png"]

     func doHttpRequest() {
            let myUrl = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.180/int.php")! //# Trailing semicolon is not needed
            var request = URLRequest(url: myUrl)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string
            let postString = "Name=\($username)&Passwort=\($password)"
            
            request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
            
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
                (data, response, error) in
                
                //# Use if-let when you want to use the unwrapped value
                if let error = error {
                    print("error=\(error)")
                    return
                }
                
                //# Use guard-let when nil has no meaning and want to exit on nil
                guard let response = response else {
                    print("Unexpected nil response")
                    return
                }
                // You can print out response object
                print("response = \(response)")
                
                //Let's convert response sent from a server side script to a NSDictionary object:
                do {
                    //# Use guard-let when nil has no meaning and want to exit on nil
                    guard let data = data else {
                        print("Unexpected nil data")
                        return
                    }
                    //#1 `mutableContainer` has no meaning in Swift
                    //#2 Use Swift Dictionary type instead of `NSDictionary`
                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any]
                    
                    if let parseJSON = json {
                        // Now we can access value of First Name by its key
                        //# Use if-let when you want to use the unwrapped value
                        if let firstNameValue = parseJSON["Name"] as? String {
                            print("firstNameValue: \(firstNameValue)")
                            let dateien =  firstNameValue.components(separatedBy: ",")
                            print(dateien)
                            
                            self.dateien = dateien
                        }
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
    }

}
```

Example of main ContentView.swift

```
struct ContentView: View {

var cv4Controller: ContentView4Controller = ContentView4Controller()

var body: some view {
 
  // your main page output
  GeometryReader { geo in 
  
     // just a guess for what you have in your main contentView
     switch(page) {
        case .main:
           ContentView2()
        default:
           ContentView4()
           break
     }

  }.environmentObject(cv4Controller) // this will make cv4Controller available to all child view structs

}


}
```

Comment: Hello,Thanks for your help, but I don't get how that should work. Could you post the corrected Code?

Comment: @TechlikeNikias Just updated my answer, I didn't run the code but it is a really basic implementation of EnvironmentObject.  I would read the documentation behind EnvironmentObject, State, StateObject and Published before proceeding as it will make your workflow much faster.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your quick and huge answer.

Comment: The Problem is that I'm using SwiftUi and therefor have no View controller.

Comment: Could you just rewrite the foreach part so that the names displayed in the next view match the ones under the image.

Comment: A view controller is only a concept, you can create the backend to your view as a regular swift class.  SwiftUI makes it very easy to implement with the ObservedObject implementation.   I do not know what you mean about the foreach loop.  The code I provided was not tested, it was just to give you an idea about how "viewcontrollers" are managed in SwiftUI @TechlikeNikias

Comment: Okay, By foreach- loop I mean the ForEach(0 ..< cv4Controller.dateien.count, id: \.self) { function. I have tried to implement the @environment loop but I didn't really know how. Is it possible to get this running with only a ContentView4 and if yes how?

Comment: No, the reason you cannot hand the var filename over to the next view is because contentView4 (along with all your other views)  are only structs, they do not actually exist in memory, it is only the code which gets rendered by SwiftUI.  Therefor any variable within your ContentView4 will not have a consistent usable value, you need to introduce a regular Swift class (which implements ObservableObject) into your project to keep track of all information which is shared by other views.  However you organize your @EnvironmentObject 's are up to you

Comment: Okay, Could you just rewrite my code so that the right filename is displayed. I have tried it for hours but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add @Binding wrapper to the "name" variable in your ts view. And pass the t variable as a binding by adding a "$". This will keep your ts name variable updated to whatever is value it has in the parent view.
Also why do you use a NavigationView in your ts View?
struct ContentView4: View {

```
    ...
    @State private var t = String()
    ...
    var body: some View {
        ...
        ZStack{
            ...
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingDetail) {
            ts(name: $t)
        }
        ...
    }
    
    func doHttpRequest() {
        ...
    }
}


struct ts: View {
    ...
    @Binding var name: String
    
    var body: some View {
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My starting code works, but It's just displaying the Filenames in a row and if I tap a random image, the name won't fit, only if I'm going down in the row and tap them. The problem is, that I don't know how to set the variable to the id, not to pass them to the next view. Has anyone got and idea how I can pass the right  filename into a variable in the for loop and read it in the next view?